# blender shuts off without warning when rendering

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I know someone already wrote about this but their answer didn't help mine. I have a project that when it renders it instantly shuts down. No signs saying an error with blender. It just turns off I don't know why this is happening. Please help me I've got the project here a well for you guys to check.

[image]

Comment: (This is not an answer but a comment...) I was able to render it on my machine without any problems. We would need the console log to know more about the issue. Try running blender from command prompt and paste here the error message that you get on console after shutdown. Also, I suppose you are using the stable 2.8?
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZkZ6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZkZ6.png)

Comment: What exact version of Blender are you using and what OS are you on? To have any chance to help we'd need to see if we can re-create the error ourselves, or get a screenshot or text copy of your error output. Running Blender from within a command prompt/terminal means that the console won't vanish when Blender crashes. If you can upload a screenshot of the tail end of such a terminal, that would go a long way towards helping others answer.

Comment: My other comment didn't go through yesterday... I'm using 2.79. My OS is windows 10 enterprise. I am not really sure how to make an external terminal/prompt I can only get internal. So all I need to know is how to make an external terminal of blender.

Comment: I found the error code!!! C:\Enter Command:blend
'blend' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Enter Command:bldeeddeecdddaiqiqqqqqqwclssss